# python: With GIL, is it still possible to have deadlocks with threading? (Not multi-processing)

Tags: python, multithreading, gil

python: With GIL, is it still possible to have deadlocks with threading? (Not multi-processing)

Below code will produce deadlock situation (Updated per Amadan, added sleep):

```
import threading
import time

# Two resources
resource1 = threading.Lock()
resource2 = threading.Lock()

def function1():
    with resource1:
        print("Thread 1 acquired resource 1")
        time.sleep(3)
        with resource2:
            print("Thread 1 acquired resource 2")
            time.sleep(3)

def function2():
    with resource2:
        print("Thread 2 acquired resource 2")
        time.sleep(3)
        with resource1:
            print("Thread 2 acquired resource 1")
            time.sleep(3)

# Create two threads
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=function1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=function2)

# Start the threads
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Wait for both threads to finish
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

print("Both threads finished execution")
```

But conceptually, even with GIL, the two threads can still trying to acquire a lock/resource that's already been acquired by the other thread.

Answer (score 2):

Your code *can* deadlock (it did for me on at least one run), but it depends on the one thread executing `with resource` between the time the other thread's two `with resource` statements.

GIL cannot prevent this deadlock. All it does is says Python can't execute more than one thread's Python code at a time. However, if `thread1` executes `with resource1` completely, `thread2` executes `with resource2` completely, before the second set of `with resource` is executed, it is a deadlock, GIL or no GIL.

If this specific timing does not happen, your code will not deadlock. For example, if `thread1` manages to get through both of its `with resource` statements without the control being passed to `thread2`, you're safe. Obviously, if the code has *any* chance of deadlock, it is bad code, but it is not that easy to notice it since it is so dependent on timing, and so, chance.

To make the deadlock a certainty, try to put `time.sleep(1)` between the two `with resource` statements in each function. It doesn't change the logic in any way, but it will make sure that the first set of `with resource` statements is executed before the second set, triggering the deadlock situation.

Comment: You're right thanks. Adding time.sleep(3) did the magic! Thanks Amadan

Comment: I updated code in original post per your suggestion, it works.

Comment: I thought your question was "why does the following code not deadlock"; I don't understand your question now...?